# How to spyOn chained method call to Restangular in Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, restangular

I am using jasmine to write unit tests for an angularJS factory that returns a call to Restangular. Take for example,

```
function funcToBeTested(params) {
  return Restangular.all('/foo').getList(params);
}
```

It is straightforward to test whether or not all() is being called on Restangular. How can I test whether getList() gets called on the returned Restangular object after all() has returned?

At the moment, I have

```
beforeEach(function() {
  module('ui.router');
  module('myService');
  module('restangular');
});

describe('funcToBeTested', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    httpBackend.expectGET('/foo').respond([]);
  });

  it('should call all on Restangular', function() {
    spyOn(Restangular, 'all').and.callThrough();
    funcToBeTested({});
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(Restangular.all).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

If I try to follow that same pattern and do something along the lines of

```
expect(Restangular.all.getList).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

things stop working. I was not able to find any literature on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `Restangular.restangularizeCollection`- similar to - https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/blob/master/test/restangularSpec.js#L425.  Using that, you could wrap your `httpbackend` result and then `spyOn` the `getList` of the 'restangularized' model.  I haven't tried this but should work.